# Why am I getting a "Property does not exist on type" error here?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

[image]

The title says it all really. I dont know why I am getting this error when I am not indexing into the variables type `{id: string}`

Full code:

```
type Root = {
  query: {
    launch: (variables: { id: string }) => { id: number }
  }
};

let root: Root = { 
  query: {
    launch({ id: "123" }) {
      return {  id: 1 }
    }
  }
 }
```

Comment: What do you intend `root.query.launch` to be, here?  A function that takes what and returns what?  Right now it looks like you're trying to [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Unpacking_fields_from_objects_passed_as_function_parameter) the argument into a variable *named* `"123"`, which is not valid, in much the same way that `let "123";` is not valid. Are you trying to destructure the argument at all?  What purpose is `"123"` supposed to serve?

Comment: You are quite right! Its a function definition not a function call, therefore its a destructure rather than an object argument. If you want to move your comment into an answer, ill flag it as correct.